# Facebook app not compatible on Android 4.3

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, facebook, compatibility

Facebook was crashing on Huawei Y530-U00 on Android 4.3, so I wiped it and tried to install it again. Play Store says that "Your device isn't compatible with this version".

I tried what is being said in the Facebook support: https://www.facebook.com/help/instagram/231705083624002
but it didn't work.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing an APK manually.

1. Go to **Settings → Security** and enable installation of apps from **unknown sources**.
2. Visit [APKMirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/facebook-2/facebook/) and click the blue download button. Once the download finishes, click the notification and install the app.

If that doesn't work, you could try the above process again with [Facebook Lite](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/facebook-2/lite/), although it looks significantly worse, and may or may not work properly (possibly depending on the country you're living in).

After you've finished installing APKs, **you should disable installing apps from unknown sources**.

- Go to **Settings → Security** and disable installation of apps from **unknown sources** -- this is important to do, because else you could be tricked into installing a malicious app.

Comment: I downloaded the app from the first link bit when I try to install it I get *live wallpaper apps are not supported*

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2754481&page=7 suggests that the fact that the phone is missing live wallpaper support makes some games crash, presumably this is the same issue (no, I don't know why Facebook would need a live wallpaper...). There is unfortunately no way to enable support for live wallpapers without flashing a custom ROM, and there are currently none for the phone.

Does Facebook Lite work? It's intended for lower-end phones like this, so it may well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the app simply is not compatible with your device, I don't see a direct fix for that but as workarounds, there might be a couple of tries.

1. Download the older version which is the latest version that supports the phone in question. Disable the auto-update if you went with this approach. The problem with this approach is that you'll have to find an older version APK source, **but such APK sources are not official usually, so beware and use the APK carefully.**
2. Use a normal browser like Google Chrome and bookmark the Facebook page as an icon on the home screen like an application. In Chrome, this could be done by opening the menu on any loaded page and clicking on "Add to home screen".

Notice that the second approach that I recommend and got some advantages over the app anyway. For example,

- Using the browser is much less power wasting compared to the app due to my experience.
- Also the browser is the full site so all features and options are there especially the new ones immediately when they're added.
- Also, I sometimes need to see the site like a desktop user's view, and that is possible via Chrome and some other browsers as well like Firefox and UC. Even *built-in* browsers support such features.
- As a disadvantage (noted by @iBug), a browser uses more data on cellular so more fees. Although I never experienced this and I browse Facebook a lot but it makes sense.

Comment: A browser uses more data on cellular → Less views and more fees

Comment: Makes sense. But less views ? last time I checked, there are some options available in the browser based FB which were not in the app. I added the point you mentioned about the fees.

Answer (score 0):

As existing answers have mentioned about installing manually from the APK, **the latest Facebook version that still supports Android 4.3 is v281.0.0.36.124 ([APKMirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/facebook-2/facebook/facebook-281-0-0-36-124-release/))**, which was released in August 2020 and has a variant for Android 4.1+.

Further version after that, [v282.0.0.40.117](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/facebook-2/facebook/facebook-282-0-0-40-117-release/) already upgraded the minimum requirement to Android 4.4+ instead.

However, *there's no guarantee that the app will still work if there's a breaking change on the server-side, which the end-users can't do anything about it.*